# Android soft keyboard covers edit input

Tags: android, android-layout

The issue appears only for LG G3. We have an edit input align at the parent bottom and when the keyboard opens it covers the input. After we close the keyboard and open it again we get the desired functionality. Already tried to set `android:softInputMode` but without success.

More info:
The app use one, main activity and multiple fragments that are displayed in a container. 
Main layout root have set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. Everthing works fine on Samsung galaxy S6, S6 edge, S5, Note 2, Nexus 5, even in emulator but not on LG G3.

Comment: have you tried android:softInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: In you parent view, set android:fitSystemWindow="false"

Comment: Thank you, I tried both solutions and none fix the problem.

Comment: show me your layout and manifest..

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your edit input with some margin bottom.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="xx dp"
```